# Fullcalendar Moment: Getting current time plus 2 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

This should be simple... using moment.js with Fullcalendar, I need to get the current time and add two hours to it.

In the select: method (or whatever you call it), I have:

```
select: function(start, end) {
```

The 'start' param contains the current time.  End appears to contain the same thing.  If I click to add an event, it details to current time to current time + 30 minutes.  What I need to do is have the ending be current time + 2 hours.  I've looked at the various docs and haven't found any references to doing something like that... so I'm blind (likely) or it's missing.  Help please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the start date and add 2 hours
http://jsfiddle.net/0fuhhh7v/1/

```
var end = start.clone().add(2,'hour');
```

For the select in fullCalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    defaultDate: '2015-11-01',
    selectable: true,
    select: function (start, end) {
        end = start.clone().add(2, 'hour');
        alert('Time block is between ' + start.format() + ' and ' + end.format());
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true
});
```